# expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token

Tags: c, gcc, token

I am getting a huge number of errors like these in my code. Can't figure out why. Here is an example of the errors:

```
In file included from mipstomachine.c:2:0,
                 from assembler.c:4:
rtype.c: In function ‘getRegister’:
rtype.c:6:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
```

My current file layout, for explanation, has mipstomachine.c, which includes assembler.c, which includes rtype.c

Here are lines 4-6 of my rtype.c

```
void rToMachine(char* line, char* mach, int currentSpot, instr currentInstruction,
                            rcode* rcodes)
{
```

I'm getting an error like this for every function declared in rtype.c

Any ideas? Thanks guys!

Comment: The message says `rtype.c: In function ‘getRegister’:`, but you didn't show the related code.  Can you give some more context?

Comment: you are missing `}` some where before that function I guess.

Comment: You have source files which includes other source files? that's not really recommended, I would actually say it's borderline wrong. Put function prototypes and structures in header files and include them in the source files when needed, then _link_ the source files together.

Comment: @Jeyaram It could be a missing semicolon too.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I agree :)

Comment: Just updated it. The lines I displayed of my code are some of the exact lines being referred to in the error.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How do you mean? Sorry, I'm not super experienced making multi-file programs in c!

Comment: If there's clearly no error at the line reported, and you just can't spot it despite Jeyaram's insight, you could try commenting out a section of your code with `#if 0` / `#endif` - if it still won't compile comment a bit more else less until you've found where it breaks.

Comment: @TonyD There is no error. It is a function declaration with everything in place. This is happening with every function declaration in the file.

Comment: Then look at the last included file of yours, and look for missing closing `}` or a missing `;`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Missing semicolon after a function declaration in one of my headers. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it would be to long to write properly in a comment, I add this as an answer instead.

When dealing with multiple source files, you should compile them one by one into object files, then in a separate step link them together to form the final executable program.

First make the object files:

```
$ gcc -Wall -g file_1.c -c -o file_1.o
$ gcc -Wall -g file_2.c -c -o file_2.o
$ gcc -Wall -g file_3.c -c -o file_3.o
```

The flag `-c` tells GCC to generate object files. The flag `-o` tells GCC what to name the output files, in this case the object files. The extra flags `-Wall` and `-g` tells GCC to generate more warnings (always good, fixing warning might actually fix things that can cause runtime errors) and to generate debug information.

Then you link the files together:

```
$ gcc file_1.o file_2.o file_3.o -o my_program
```

This command tells GCC to invoke the linker and link all named object files into the executable program `my_program`.

---

If there are structures and/or functions that are needed in multiple source files, then that's when you use header files.

For example, lets say you have a structure `my_structure` and a function `my_function` that needs to be used from multiple source file, you could create a header file `header_1.h` like this:

```
/* Include guard, to protect the file from being included multiple times
 * in the same source file
 */
#ifndef HEADER_1
#define HEADER_1

/* Define a structure */
struct my_structure
{
    int some_int;
    char some_string[32];
};

/* Declare a function prototype */
void my_function(struct my_structure *);

#endif
```

This file can now be included in a source file like this:

```
#include "header_1.h"
```